# How to catch Ldap error and redirect to specified page when using Devise and devise_ldap_authenticatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap

I would like to show my login page with error message like "The system cannot log you on at this time. Please try again later" when there is ldap error during the login process.

Currently, I have used the custom_failure.rb approach as described in
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated
and it is able to catch error like invalid username / password and I have redirected it to the login page
showing the error messages as desired without problem.
But this approach cannot catch the ldap errors.

These ldap errors are shown as a very raw html page like the following:

Errno::ETIMEDOUT in Devise::SessionsController#create

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2)

Rails.root: C:/extratxt/2.2.0/source/ruby/messaging
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

Request

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "user"=>{"username"=>"administrator",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "remember_me"=>"0"},
 "commit"=>"Sign in"}
```

Show session dump

Show env dump
Response

Headers:

None

How can I prevent this and instead show my specified page (e.g. login page with my own error message) ? 
Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to override the create session action, but there are a couple steps required to get it working. First, copy the devise views (if you haven't already done so) with

```
rails g devise:views
```

Then you need to create a sessions_controller.rb file that extends Devise::SessionsController:

```
# /app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  # copied from [...]/gems/devise-1.4.5/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
  # To find the path to your gem, use 'bundle show devise' 
  def create

    begin
      resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
      set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
    rescue Net::LDAP::LdapError
      # handle your error
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_session_path, :notice => $!.to_s }
        format.json { render json: $!.to_s }
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Finally, in your config/routes.rb, you need to tell devise to use your customized controller:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => :sessions }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Finally I have tried your suggestion and it worked nicely. I have made the following 2 changes: 1) redirect_to :controller => 'mycontroller', :action => 'myaction', ..  2) devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }

Comment: Glad it worked. Can you mark the answer as "Accepted Solution"? :-)

Comment: Yes, done. It takes some time to figure out how to mark it as "Accepted Solution". The "Tick" is too easy to overlook!

Comment: this was helpful.  I would emphasize that people should used the code from their current version of devise to create the override, and not just blindly copypasta the code above.